# Why does my Dragon King Greataxe do less damage than my Zweihander?

Tags: dark-souls

I just got enough strength to wield the Dragon King Greataxe in two hands (34) but even though it does 80 more damage than my Zweihander at 380 my Zweihander does more damage when I actually attack with it. Is this because I don't meet the full 50 strength required to use it?

Answer (score 5):

It's because dragon weapons don't scale with stats, the letters at the bottom of the zweihanders stats are how well it scales with certain attributes. Hence why barely anyone uses dragon weapons. Where it has your zweihanders damage output, next to it there will be a +something so it's standard damage plus that extra bit

Comment: FYI there are 4 dragon weapons that have stat scaling: Moonlight Greatsword, dragon tooth, Priscillas dagger, and Dragon Bone Fists.

Comment: FYI+1 Raw items, crystal items, chaos items, and other also don't stack with stats